# Associated const in size of returned array

Tags: rust

Consider the following `trait`:

```
pub trait Representable {
    const SIZE: usize;

    fn get(&self) -> [u8; SIZE];
    fn set(&mut self, value: [u8; SIZE]);
}
```

I would like to implement it for any `struct` that can be represented as a fixed-size array of bytes. To this end, I added to the `trait` an associated constant `SIZE` such that the representation returned by `get` and accepted by `set` is `SIZE` bytes long.

However, when I try to compile I get this message:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `SIZE` in this scope
 --> src/bytewise/representable.rs:4:27
  |
4 |     fn get(&self) -> [u8; SIZE];
  |                           ^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `SIZE` in this scope
 --> src/bytewise/representable.rs:5:35
  |
5 |     fn set(&mut self, value: [u8; SIZE]);
  |                                   ^^^^ not found in this scope
```

So, well, now I am confused. I can't think of much more than "but... but it's right there". What am I missing?

Comment: don't think is possible currently, https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f161dbf52739e7d0c0107ec64df698f0, congratulation for your intern compiler error

Comment: I think this fails because traits are namespaces, but not scopes. However, I would have expected `Self::SIZE` to work; looks like a compiler bug (especially with the ICE that Stargateur found).

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42863

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve almost the same by using an associated type:

```
pub trait Representable {
    type T;

    fn get(&self) -> Self::T;
    fn set(&mut self, value: Self::T);
}

pub struct ReprA;
impl Representable for ReprA{
    type T = [u8; 10];

    fn get(&self) -> Self::T{
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn set(&mut self, value: Self::T){
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

pub struct ReprB;
impl Representable for ReprB{
    type T = [u8; 50];

    fn get(&self) -> Self::T{
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn set(&mut self, value: Self::T){
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! :) Thanks.