# any way to associate constant with type in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to associate a constant defined in my trait, and use it in a generic function.

```
trait My {
    const C: usize;
}

fn f<T>() -> [i32; T::C] where T: My {
    unimplemented!();
}
```

But rust can not handle this

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2d51315ba58f92d0e29bdac32115a62

Is there any other way to get constant from type in generic function?

Comment: Associating a constant with a type works just fine. Using that constant in the type system, however, does not. You'll have to wait for const generics support in Rust (expected later this year).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Associated const in size of returned array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871619/associated-const-in-size-of-returned-array)

Comment: Update to @MaraBos's comment: a limited subset of const generics will likely be stabilized in a couple releases!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [generic_array](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.13.0/generic_array/) crate - this doesn't let you use fixed-size Rust arrays, but you can express an array length as an associated type

```rust
trait My {
  type C: ArrayLength<i32>;
}
```

And then refer to it with a trait bound

```rust
fn f<T>() -> GenericArray<i32, T::C> where T: My {
  ...
}
```

You can then also get the constant value from the type with [to_usize](https://docs.rs/typenum/1.10.0/typenum/marker_traits/trait.Unsigned.html#tymethod.to_usize).